# Steps for evaluating $\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{x^3 (\ln x)^2}{e^\sqrt{x}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

What are the steps for evaluating this limit?
$$\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{x^3 (\ln x)^2}{e^\sqrt{x}}$$

On online limit calculator says it is equal to $0$ after applying l'hopital's rule 8 times, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}0≤\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{x^3 (\ln x)^2}{e^\sqrt{x}}&=\lim_{u \to\infty} \frac{u^6 (2\ln u)^2}{e^u}\\
&=4\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{u^6 (\ln u)^2}{e^u}\\
&≤4\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u^8}{e^u}\\
&=0.\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice answer which still leave some work to complete to the OP. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much for reviewing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$0 \le \frac{x^3 (\ln x)^2}{e^\sqrt{x}} \le \frac{x^5}{e^{\sqrt x}}\to 0$$

Comment: @hosainghoraba The sigma sign is the expansion of $e$.

Comment: @hosainghoraba You could just leave it as my last edit though. It will be clear

Comment: Nice answer  +! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you. First, I was writing up to big O orders, but the asker doesn't seem to know them yet.